# Hot Chocolate + MongoDB: Getting data from many collection in single task

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, graphql, hotchocolate

My `Product` entity consists of:

- templateId
- parameterIds
- categoryIds

I am getting 100 products in one batch.

I've created data loaders and resolvers for each of references. Now I get template, parameters and categories in three single calls (get categories, then get parameters and at the end get product template). The problem is that I see in the logs, that all requests are one after one.

I would like to do something like this await

```
Task.WhenAll(getTemplatesTask, getParametersTask, getCategoriesTask)
```

in order to save some time.

Is it possible in hot chocolate integration with mongodb? It causes that it is slower than my current REST endpoint.

EDIT:
This is part of my code:

```
public class ProductType : ObjectType<ProductDocument>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<ProductDocument> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.BindFieldsExplicitly();
        descriptor.Name("Product");            
        descriptor.Field("productTemplate")
            .Type<ProductTemplateType>()
            .ResolveWith<ProductTemplatesResolver>(r => r.GetProductTemplate(default!, default!, default));
        descriptor.Field("categories")
            .Type<ListType<CategoryType>>()
            .ResolveWith<CategoriesResolver>(...); //Resolver use GroupedDataLoader
        descriptor.Field("parameters")
            .Type<ListType<ParameterType>>()
            .ResolveWith<ParametersResolver>(...); //Resolver use GroupedDataLoader
    }
}

public class ProductTemplatesResolver
{
    public Task<ProductTemplateDocument> GetProductTemplate([Parent] ProductDocument product,
        ProductTemplatesBatchDataLoader loader,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return loader.LoadAsync(product.ProductTemplateId, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public class ProductTemplatesBatchDataLoader : BatchDataLoader<int, ProductTemplateDocument>
{
    private readonly ProductsDbContext _dbContext;
    
    public ProductTemplatesBatchDataLoader(IBatchScheduler batchScheduler, ProductsDbContext dbContext, DataLoaderOptions? options = null) : base(batchScheduler, options)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    protected override async Task<IReadOnlyDictionary<int, ProductTemplateDocument>> LoadBatchAsync(IReadOnlyList<int> keys, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var pts = await _dbContext.ProductTemplates
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => keys.Contains(x.Id))
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        return pts.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x);
    }
}
```

It executes all data loaders not in one time, but when first is finished then second is started

Thanks

Comment: Really hard to give an answer without seeing what your code looks like...

Comment: I've added missing code

Comment: This should definitely be execute in parallel, can you open an issue on GitHub and add a repro?

Comment: I've verified it again and I've made time trackers in incorrect place. It works correctly. Thanks